# Spring resttemplate InvalidMediaTypeException. Invalid mime type due to Invalid token character '@' in token

Tags: spring, http, resttemplate

The api I am calling responds with a content-type that has `@` in the value for in response to my resttemplate call.

```
        final HttpHeaders headers = new HttpHeaders();
        headers.set(HttpHeaders.ACCEPT, "key=abcd@def");
        final ResponseEntity<String> responseEntity = resttemplate.exchange(
                path, HttpMethod.GET, new HttpEntity<>(null, headers),
                String.class);
```

```
Response Header
content-type: key=abc@def
```

Error I get

```
org.springframework.http.InvalidMediaTypeException: 
Invalid mime type "key=abcd@def": Invalid token character '@' in token "abcd@def"
```

Comment: The error seems reasonable given that the mimetype is invalid. What's your question?

Comment: @Evert I don't have control over the server. How can I make spring rest template like it, ignore it or work around it so that header is removed before it reaches the rest tempate parsing logic..